# spring cloud config server git for local file

Tags: spring, git, server, cloud, config

I want get the data from local file using spring cloud config server git.

I have tried with below Yaml config but it is not working.

server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: file:///C:/spring-boot-ws/demo-springcloud-m2-configserver-git/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-master/

My folder Structure is like

C: > spring-boot-ws > demo-springcloud-m2-configserver-git > pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-master > station1 > s1rates.properties

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggest, using `git` means that you have to set the uri of the repository containing your configurations and not a local files. If you want to use local files you should configure your server like this:

```
spring:
   profiles:
     active: native
   cloud:
      config:
        server:
          native:
            searchLocations: file:///...
```